# docker clean up container overhead

Tags: docker, containers, disk-access

I have two docker containers running, where  the diskspace is as follows:

```
user$ sudo docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              2                   1                   448.3MB             1.84kB (0%)
Containers          2                   2                   284.4MB             0B (0%)
Local Volumes       7                   2                   418.8kB             176.4kB (42%)
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

If I check diskusage I get:

```
root:/var/lib/docker# du -ah --max-depth=1
45G     ./containers
```

What can I do to keep the containers (since I made a lot of configuration) but remove the obvious overhead?

Comment: I found that the space-consuming file is <containername>-json.log. Can I remove the file?

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below command the clean the system as

1. This will remove:

   - all stopped containers
   - all networks not used by at least one container
   - all dangling images
   - all dangling build cache

```
docker system prune -f
```

And yes, you can remove the son file as well.

Comment: I just have the two containers which I want to keep definitely. My problem seems to be the unrestricted size of logfile.

Comment: When you run `docker system prune -f`, it will not remove the running containers or images and yes you can delete the logs file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker system prune -f`, but, from my experience, it is not cleaning all that can be cleaned up.

For that, I've created a simple Docker image that does all the needed cleaning using only one command:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock tikalci/tci-docker-cleanup:latest
```

For more details, see: https://github.com/TikalCI/tci-docker-cleanup